# Get all baklink domains of any particular domain using php

Tags: php, hyperlink, dns, alexa-internet

Hii to all I am stuck here
I need a list of all domains which having backlinks of any particular domain.
Can anyone help me for this?
Please provide me some link or some api procedure to get all the backlink.
I had searched on alexa they provided the linksin backlink detail but not have any api request for that.
I got a php script to get the rank of any domain it is having the all backlink count of that domain But I need the all the domains name at the same time.

```
   $url="msn.com";
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.$url);
$rank=(int)$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->TEXT;
$web=(string)$xml->SD[1]->POPULARITY->attributes()->URL;
$backlink=(int)$xml->SD[0]->LINKSIN->attributes()->NUM;
echo $web." has Alexa Rank ".$rank." has backlink: ".$backlink;
```

Comment: till you are not getting back links API you can use 
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
This will also use full to you..

Comment: I think there is no free backlink API anymore since Yahoo has closed down its own API. The problem is that creating a backlink database is a very expensive process, because you have to crawl the whole net. So vendors sell it for money.

Comment: I have edited my php code part.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to get all the linkin or backlink detail using api ... pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be little bit useful to you.. I found it from internet world.

```
function check_back_link($remote_url, $your_link) {
  $match_pattern = preg_quote(rtrim($your_link, "/"), "/"); 
  $found = false;
  if($handle = @fopen($remote_url, "r")){
    while(!feof($handle)){
      $part = fread($handle, 1024);
      if(preg_match("/<a(.*)href=[\"']".$match_pattern."(\/?)[\"'](.*)>(.*)<\/a>/", $part)){
        $found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  return $found;
}
```

**An example of the function in use.**

```
if(check_back_link('http://www.google.com','http://www.yahoo.com')){
  echo 'link found';
}else{
  echo 'link NOT found';
};
// this prints 'link NOT found', unfortunately...
```

**Updated With MSN**

```
function msn_backs($url){ 
    $site = fopen('http://search.live.com/results.aspx?q=link%3A'.urlencode($url),'r'); 
    while($cont = fread($site,1024657)){ 
        $total .= $cont; 
    } 
    fclose($site); 
    $match_expression = '/<h5>Page 1 of (.*) results<\/h5>/Us'; 
    preg_match($match_expression,$total,$matches); 
    return $matches[1]; 
}
```

Comment: No I need all the linkin detail of the other site which having link for msn.com